# How is an image hidden behind/protected by <canvas>?

Tags: google-chrome, images, download, google-maps

It's possible to download an image from a place from google maps?

https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7825172,-73.9655178,3a,75y,187h,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPw3Dzrmndch3Izgay4SN5--MfJd_X8bOWgEXys!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPw3Dzrmndch3Izgay4SN5--MfJd_X8bOWgEXys%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i5184!8i3456?hl=en

I tried using Chrome's inspect element but the image is hidden somehow behind some code:

```
<canvas width="2560" height="633" id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" style="width: 2048px; height: 506px;" tabindex="-1"></canvas>
```

I guess the image is hidden behind **class="widget-scene-canvas"**
Is there a way to learn how the image is hidden behind the canvas?

Is it just an image with a transparent box above (so I can't right click it > Save image...)?

Answer (score 3):

No. Html `<canvas>` is not even an image. It's just like you're trying to download an image from online games or youtube. Your best bet is screenshot them or use a tool for that.

But if you want to download maps from Google Maps, why don't switch to your phone and [download from it](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)?

Comment: Have you checked the link in the question? It's not a link to the map but to the photo of a POI.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for chrome called "[Enable right click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-right-click/hhojmcideegachlhfgfdhailpfhgknjm)". With it, you can do right click and download the image. After trying many extensions and many other ways, this is the only one that has worked for me. I do not know how it works but it works!

Comment: At first I thought this has nothing to do with the question but it appears that `canvas` element has context-menu option called "Save image as..." although the URL cannot be found anywhere on the page, so basically this extension you've provided really answers the question. Thanks!